# Java: Any way to speed up this replacer?

Tags: java, performance, keyboard

My virtualkeyboard is nearly done, i am trying to increase performance.

I want to aask you. That is here any better / faster solution for replacing characters in buttons.

getButtons() => List< JButton >

there are 52 buttons where text needs to be replaced, 16 buttons is replaced by other character, and 36 is uppercased.
on 1.6GHz dualcore it takes about 0.5-0.7 sec. I want to do it about 0.2-0.3  or instant :D

> ```
>    public void toLowerCase()
>     {
>
>         String[] from =
>         {
>             "§", "'", "\"", "+", "!", "%", "/", "=", "(", ")", ":", "_", "*", "#", ";", "?"
>         };
>         String[] to =
>         {
>             "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", ".", "-", "\\", "$", ",", "ß"
>         };
>
>         char curChar;
>         for (int i = 0; i < getButtons().size(); i++)
>         {
>             curChar = toChar(((JButton) getButtons().get(i)).getText());
>             for (int x = 0; x < from.length; x++)
>             {
>                 if (compareChar(curChar, toChar(from[x])))
>                 {
>                     ((JButton) getButtons().get(i)).setText(to[x]);
>                 }
>             }
>             ((JButton) getButtons().get(i)).setText(((JButton) getButtons().get(i)).getText().toString().toLowerCase());
>         }
>         repaint();
>     }
> ```

Thanks very much for everybody :-)

Comment: You could use a `Map` whose keys are `from` and values are `to`, that would eliminate the inner `for` loop (where it looks like you're searching for the match).

Comment: I think 0.5-0.7 comes from the overhead of `setText` `toLowerCase` and `repaint`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use a map :

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("§", "0");
...

String toChar = map.get(curChar);
if (toChar!=null) ((JButton) getButtons().get(i)).setText(toChar);
```

But you should initialize the map outside the method and reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing the replace you would could just statically initialize the different types of keyboards.

```
static Map<String,String> defaultKeyBoard = ...;  
static Map<String,String> otherKeyBoard = ...;  

static  
{    
    //populate keyboard maps
}
```

Now you can flip between the different keyboards based on a boolean condition.

If you only compute it once you save all that time and simply do a full replace each time without rebuilding the maps or doing expensive computations.

Comment: its good idea, but this solution does not fit into my whole code

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this as an object oriented design question rather than a data structures / algorithms question. Try something like this:

```
public class ToggleCaseJButton extends JButton {

    private final String upperCaseText;

    private final String lowerCaseText;

    public ToggleCaseJButton(String upperCaseText, String lowerCaseText) {
        this.upperCaseText = upperCaseText;
        this.lowerCaseText = lowerCaseText;
    }

    public void setUpperCase() {
        setText(upperCaseText);
    }

    public void setLowerCase() {
        setText(lowerCaseText);
    }
}
```

Then the keyboard would have something like this:

```
private final List<ToggleCaseJButton> keys = new ArrayList<ToggleCaseJButton>();

private void setupKeys() {
    keys.add(new ToggleCaseJButton("!", "1");
    keys.add(new ToggleCaseJButton("@", "2");
    // etc...
}


public void setUpperCase() {
    for (ToggleCaseJButton key : keys) {
        key.setUpperCase();
    }
    repaint();
}    

public void setLowerCase() {
    for (ToggleCaseJButton key : keys) {
        key.setLowerCase();
    }
    repaint();
}
```